# Abort background process

Tags: gvim, background

Sometimes when a background process in Vim runs (in my case, compiling a poorly written LaTeX document) the background process stops which makes Vim unresponsive.

Terminating the process from terminal solves the problem but is cumbersome to execute. <kbd>Ctrl c</kbd> does not seem to work.

How should the background process be aborted?

Preferably, the process should be terminated but a solution that just unfreezes Vim is fine.

My current command is:
`:silent exec "!make"<CR>`

A solution is to add a `make vim` in the makefile that ignores the errors but it would be nice to be able to force quit the process.

Comment: Do you need a `synchronous` solution (Vim waiting the compiler) or could you consider an `asynchronous` solution (Vim not waiting, the compiler working on the background).

Comment: Try C-\, which is a bit more forceful than C-c

Comment: Thank you @D.BenKnoble, that worked perfectly and also terminated the background process! If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd>  (SIGQUIT) works in most unix terminals I’ve used and is more forceful than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> (SIGINT). Try it when a program is misbehaving (but be careful hammering it in a nested context, where you might accidentally stop the inner and outer programs “unkindly”).

Comment: @Ben is it a Vim shortcut or only a terminal shortcut? Do we have to first switch to the terminal with Ctrl-Z

Comment: It's a terminal-level key, same as C-c, since it sends signals directly to the active process.

Comment: For me, it also works in gVim.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to use the [asyncrun](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim) plugin.

If you were used to run `:!mycompiler.sh`, it let you run your compiler with a command like:

```
:AsyncRun mycompiler.sh
```

The output is sent to the QuickList and parsed using the `errorformat`.

You can stop the compiler using the command:

```
:AsyncStop
```

Comment: Thank you, I would prefer async but also I don't want any unnecessary dependencies, if the answer is that it is impossible to abort, then that's fine.

Comment: Is the plugin an unnecessary dependencies? I'm not aware of standard asynchronous functionality and I believe it doesn't exist :-)

Comment: I see your point but always try to avoid all plugins.

Comment: I understand. I have no solution to propose :-/